# Debugging the App in WindowsPhone 8 Device

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am having a windowsPhone 8(lumia) device and I want to debug my App in Real Device.I used Developer Phone Registration.The problem i am facing now is,If click register button a small window appears and Vanishes after 15 seconds and cant able to register,plz help me.

Comment: Does the phone registration tool says that it identifies your device in the status when the phone is connected via USB? Can you tell us what the small window says? Take a screenshot of it before it disappears and post it.

Comment: Try registering it on a friend's computer who has VS 2012 installed.

Comment: What is the status of the device in the registration tool? Is the phone PIN-unlocked when you are trying to register?

Comment: Yep,the status shows that a windows Phone 8 device is connected and register button is visible.On clicking the register button I am gettting the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you're running Developer Phone Registration from **Windows Phone SDK 8.0**, on **Windows 8 - 64 bit**.
- Unlock phone screen during registration
- Windows will ask you to enter a valid Windows Phone Developer account (which cost you $100)
- You need to connect to Internet
- Are the date and time set correctly on the phone? In SETTINGS | date + time, turn off the Set automatically setting and then retry registration. After registration succeeds, turn this setting on again.